# Cannot find module './my_file.scss' or its corresponding type declarations error in VsCode

Tags: reactjs

I am using `gatsby`

I have this piece of code in my component:

```
import React, { CSSProperties } from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import * as styles from './my_file.scss';  

//on prev line, I am getting: 

Cannot find module './my_file.scss' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

this is my_file.scss:

```
.text-bold {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

this is my `gatsby-config.js` file (i don't know if this file is needed to fix this problem)

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const path = require('path');
const pxtorem = require('postcss-pxtorem');
const plugins = [
    {
        resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-sass',
        options: {
            additionalData: '@import "utils/_index.scss";',
            sassOptions: {
                includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/scss')],
            },
            postCssPlugins: [
                pxtorem({
                    propList: ['*'],
                    selectorBlackList: [/^html$/],
                }),
            ],
        },
    },
];

module.exports = {
    siteMetadata: {
        siteUrl: 'https://www.yourdomain.tld',
    },
    plugins,
};
```

this works without errors in the browser, but in `vsCode` I am getting this error, how can I fix it?